# Recommendations for plotting (chart) component?

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I am searching for a widget or control to plot a time-series of data.  Basically plot(x,y) where x and y are Nx1 vectors.  I am looking but haven't found much and any suggestions would be great!  Thanks.

Comment: In the Windows world, it's called a 'control', not a 'widget'.

Comment: Is there something wrong with TChart which ships with C++Builder?

Comment: TChart, out of the box, with TFastLineSeries will get the job done

Comment: As owner Gigasoft, see our [7 meg charting demo](http://www.gigasoft.com/delphicharting.html) as part of researching Delphi charting.

Answer (score 9):

Use TeeChart, supplied with Delphi. Good for time series and also real time graphs.

Comment: And if you want anti-aliased drawing of the Chart on screen, you can save it to a EMF file, then render it using our [Open Source GDI+ wrapper](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/04/02/Antialiased-drawing-from-TMetaFile). I used this on several projects (via our Report engine), and it worked well. Good old TChart is looking much better using GDI+ drawing, at least for the end-customer side.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer TJvChart from the [Jedi VCL library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/), but then I wrote the TJvChart, or most of it anyways.   The reason I recommend it is that it's free, but it has some limitations, including a lack of proper zoom-in and zoom-out capability.

I don't like to use any component in my apps that does not include source code, and generally caution against closed source component use in any serious project, so plan to buy the TeeChart source code if you'll need to use the component.   I'm not anti Tee-Chart though; If you choose to use it in a commercial project, go ahead it's great too. Just be aware that it's really 100% worth buying the source for anything you really want to use in a serious way.

Quick start:
 1. Download and install JVCL.
 2. Open included JvChart demos.

Stackoverflow style tutorial:
  1. drop TJvChart on a form.
  2. write this code:

```
  JvChart1.Options.PenCount := 1;
  JvChart1.Data.ValueCount := 3;
  // set values for [penIndex=0, valueIndex=0..2 ]
  JvChart1.Data.Value[0,  1] := 1;
  JvChart1.Data.Value[0,  2] := 3;
  JvChart1.Data.Value[0,  3] := 5;
  JvChart1.PlotGraph;
```

[image]

Comment: TeeChart comes with source code. You just have to pay for it. Any serious project IMHO should use well supported components, commercial or not (and obtaining source code for a long term project is always advisable). Otherwise your argument could be used to use FPC/Lazarus instead of Delphi, because Delphi is a closed source application that doesn't come with full source code.

Comment: Which performs better with large data sets?

Comment: @David, I must say that I have no experience with JvChart. TeeChart has TFastLineSeries as you mentioned. Setting DrawAllPoints to False will have great impact on drawing speed. Also it is possible to define all series outside of TeeChart which reduces memory footprint for large series. See [www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php] for more information. This is hard to beat in performance for a standard library, although I'm using a home cooked component in some of my applications which requires a higher state of reliability.

Comment: I said that ldsandon; I said it comes with source code if you pay for it. Thanks for saying it twice. ;-)

Comment: The big limitation in TJvChart that would affect lots of people is the inability to do a mouse based zoom in and out. in that case, if you need that, you really do want TeeChart.